# Как в регулярных выражениях использовать что то на подобие тернарных операторов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как в регулярных выражениях использовать что то на подобие тернарных операторов? 
Т.е в зависимости от подстроки заменять на ту или иную?
Напрмиер:

```
Pressure->TabVisible = false;
Temperature->TabVisible = true;
```

заменить на

```
HideTab(ui->Pressure);
ShowTab(ui->Temperature);
```

По отдельности я делал в Notepad++ так :

```
(\w+)->TabVisible = true -> ShowTab\(ui->\1\)
(\w+)->TabVisible = false -> HideTab\(ui->\1\)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следующее регулярное выражение:

```
(\w+)->TabVisible\s*=\s*(?:(true)|(false))
```

Заменяете на:

```
(?3HideTab\(ui->$1\):ShowTab\(ui->$1\)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** Шаблон замены можно сократить до `(?3Hide:Show)Tab\(ui->$1\)`.

Спасибо за комментарий @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: Шаблон замены можно сократить до `(?3Hide:Show)Tab\(ui->$1\)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, благодарю, действительно можно.